# sidekiq error when deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano, sidekiq

I have some problem when I trying to deploy Sinatra and sidekiq with capistrano.

In mygem file :

```
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq' , github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'

Capfile:
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'

Gemfile.lock
capistrano-sidekiq (0.3.3)

sidekiq (3.2.0)
```

Error when deployed:

```
**Don't know how to build task 'restart'**
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:10:in `after'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.3.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.cap:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.3.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.cap:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.3.3/lib/capistrano/sidekiq.rb:2:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-sidekiq-0.3.3/lib/capistrano/sidekiq.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/projects/feed_bidder/feed_bidder_offline/Capfile:6:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/projects/feed_bidder/feed_bidder_offline/Capfile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Also when I try to deploy via `cap production sidekiq:start -T`

Comment: Do you have the `restart` rake task in deploy.rb file?

Comment: No, the restart task should be in  capistrano-sidekiq gem, i'm right?